# table alias in linq edmx

Tags: linq

I am trying to replicate something that would be simple with a stored procedure.

I have a set of tables like so:
acem__main
acem__child
beta__main
beta_child
xyz__main
xyz__child

In my edmx, I have the acem_main and acem_child linked via a primary/secondary key.

However depending on who logs in I would like to utilise the data of either acem, beta or xyz.

I cannot imagine how to fit this into linq - can anyone help please?

Comment: Trying to understand your question here. Are you asking that a specific user who logs in gets data from table1 and user2 logs in gets data from table2?

Comment: yes - I want the ability to dynamically change the tables for the source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a method that returns an IEnumerable and take a user as arguments. In the method, create three Linq queries for acem, beta or xyz and return the result from the query that correspond to the given user.